# How to store a user's cart information without using models or authentication in Django?

Tags: python, django

I am making an ecommerce website, I use this view to allow user to add items in cart:

```
def add_to_cart(request, slug):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        item = get_object_or_404(Item, slug=slug)
        order_item = OrderedItems.objects.create(item=item, user=request.user, ordered=False)
        order_qs = Order.objects.filter(user=request.user, ordered=False)
        if order_qs.exists():
            order = order_qs[0]
            order_item.quantity = request.POST.get('number')
            order_item.save()
            order.items.add(order_item)
            return redirect('core:home')

        order = Order.objects.create(user=request.user, ordered=False)
        order.items.add(order_item)
        order_item.quantity = request.POST.get('number')
        order_item.save()
        return redirect('core:product_detail', slug=slug)
```

The models and everything else in this website depends heavily on user authentication.
I keep track of which user ordered which items through `Order` model:

```
class OrderedItems(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(
        Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='ordereditems')
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

So, how do I store a user's cart information without using models or authentication  using cookies or sessions? Please kindly explain it with code.

[Github link](https://github.com/basirpayenda/ecommerce-website) to current project.

Thank You

Comment: Why you don't want to store cart items into the database?

Comment: Even if you are using djangos session engine: You have to store the data somewhere. You dont want to store that in the cookie. So you can use your database and relate some kind of CardObject to the session (no login required) or you could use a cache like redis. But why dont you want to use ur db?

Comment: I just find this website https://shopmrbeast.com/ making job easier for clients without authentication headache for some lazy users

Comment: @BasirPayenda so, for that you can use your DB as per errorinpersona's suggestion. You must need to store it somewhere.

Comment: I store all other information in database, but I only want to add this functionality that website should remember orders of unauthenticated users

Comment: Thats fine. So you just need to connect your CardModel to a session rather than to a user - still stuff lives in DB.